# Python - AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'

Tags: python

I have a list of mutable objects which is an attribute of a class.

```
self.matriceCaracteristiques
```

I would like to keep a copy of it, so that the objects will change during execution as for the original list, but not their order in the list itself (that is what I want to preserve and "restore" after execution).

```
copy_of_matCar = self.matriceCaracteristiques[:] #to preserve the order of the objects 
#that will be changed during execution
```

When it's time to restore the list, I've tried making this:

```
self.matriceCaracteristiques = copy_of_matCar[:]
```

but it doesn't work cause although the `copy_of_matCar` has a different order (specifically, the one that the attribute had before some code execution), the other `self.matriceCaracteristiques` remains exactly the same although the instruction. 
So I have thought to make a deepcopy of it, by following the Python reference:

```
import copy
self.matriceCaracteristiques = copy.deepcopy(copy_of_matCar)
```

However, what I get is the following error:

```
  self.matriceCaracteristiques = copy.deepcopy(copy_of_matCar)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'
```

Any idea how I can fix this problem and get a deepcopy of the list `copy_of_matCar` to be assigned to the `self.matriceCaracteristiques` one?

Comment: Did you name another function "copy" somewhere in your program?

Comment: Try replacing your import with "from copy import deepcopy" and then change the call to be "deepcopy(copy_of_matCar)" and see if that gets you anywhere.

Comment: Something is shadowing the `copy` object. If I type in the console `import copy` and then `copy.deepcopy`, I get `<function deepcopy at ...>`

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your error. You are leaving out some relevant code.

Comment: @Decency thanks, it worked out. Now it's "working". I say this cause it's still having the same problem, the instruction `self.matriceCaracteristiques = deepcopy(copy_of_matCar)` leaves totally the left-object totally indifferent to the command (it's still the same than before). Shouldn't a deep copy wildly put everything is in `copy_of_matCar` into the `self.matriceCaracteristiques`?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Yes. We're going to need to see more code to help you with the problem.

Comment: @JoelCornett I've tried to replicate the error myself in a new module but I wasn't able, the code is too huge to be copied here (and I've no idea what part could be relevant since I cannot understand the error neither the traceback) and it's most probably something shadowing the copy object as ikaros45 was saying. Now the error is fixed (by just using deepcopy) but still no way of getting a copy of this object...

Comment: @Decency ok I will try to do it but the project is huge and impossible to be copied here anywhere. I've no clue what part of code you might need to see, do you have any idea?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ: I'm having trouble understanding what you expect from `deepcopy`. `deepcopy` will create a new deep copy of the list `copy_of_matCar`. This means a new list with the same values, but no references to any other list. Is this what you want?

Comment: I will start with a description of what the list contains. Inside the list there are: 1) 8 class instances, 2 of them are re-instantiated between the creation of the copy and the re-attribution of the copy to its original list (that's actually the reason why I need to keep a copy); 2) 4 tuples (themselves containing class instances not changing over the running code); 3) 5 static lists.

Comment: Did you put `from copy import copy` anywhere?

Comment: @JoelCornett, oh, no reference? No I don't think so. What I need is to preserve the order of the objects in the list within a for-loop (but just the order, not the objects inside that instead need to change for every loop); so, after every execution, I can restore the order of the originary list by just giving back the copy to the list.

Comment: Do this to find where that `copy` module is coming from.. `import copy
print copy.__file__`. This will print path of copy module you are importing.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ: Hmmm, with the amount of explaining you have to do about what you're trying to achieve, it's possible that you're going about this the wrong way. The red flag that leads me to believe you're not going about this the best way is that `matriceCaracteristiques` is not homogenous.

Comment: @JoelCornett yes, unfortunately is not homogeneuos (there are class instances, tuples and lists). But so what would be a good way to keep a copy of the order of the list, if any?

Comment: Is there a reason why the list becomes unordered in the first place? That's what I would try to fix first. If that's not possible, than do the items in the list have unique identifying characteristics that could be used to indicate their place in the list? You could then `sort` the list with an appropriate key function to restore the list to the original order.

Comment: @JoelCornett, the elements in the list must move within it for evaluation reasons (they contain elements that have to be valuated first depending on the value they assume step-by-step). Unfortunately not, there's not a unique characteristique. I'm trying to sort it out in another way (trying to identifying some forced unique characteristiques and re-sorting the list right after), thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 13):

I am facing the same problem, and tried many ways.
The following way resolves my problem:
change

```
import copy
dict = {...}
copy.deepcopy()
```

to

```
from copy import deepcopy
dict = {...}
deepcopy()
```

Answer (score 5):

What's been suggested in the comment is the source of the problem: there's something shadowing `copy` in your module, **after** you imported the `copy` module.

Consider for instance the following modules:

```
# In some_module_1.py
from copy import copy


# In some_module_2.py
import copy
# `copy` refers to the module, as expected
print('deepcopy' in dir(copy))  # True

from some_module_1 import *
# `copy` got shadowed, it is now actually referring to `copy.copy`
print('deepcopy' in dir(copy))  # False
```

Because I imported everything from `some_module_1`, I also imported the function `copy` I imported over there. This means it now shadows the module `copy` imported 4 lines above. Therefore python properly complains that `deepcopy` isn't an attribute of the function `copy.copy`, hence the error

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find other copy module in your code.
For example, ...

```
from numpy.lib.function_base import copy
```

Please remove other copy modules.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).